# Еще об интернет-жаргоне

Tags: жаргон, этимология

В последнее время в социальных сетях часто используется слово "баян" для обозначения темы "с бородой"

Но пишут это слово по-разному: кто "боян", кто "баян", и даже "бойан".

Как же "правильно"
И связан ли этот термин с Бояном?

Comment: Давно Вас не было... На Универсиаде волонтером трудились?)))

Comment: Да нет, нашла другие форумы. Я ведь математик.

Comment: Расскажете, какие?

Comment: Один - dxdy, туда хожу за серьезными задачами.
Другой - матфорум МГУ, он практически не модерируется. Там можно поцапаться с ферматистами и другими чудиками, поругаться с любителями Форекса. Иногда дать совет начинающему, или не-математику. В общем, малыми силами почувствовать себя Большой Фигурой.

Comment: Ясно. Ну - удачи. 
А что Вы их раньше не видели?

Comment: dxdy - видела, но не сидела. А мгу-шный мне здесь (в смысле на Математике) подсказала одна собеседница. Но он вырождается без модерирования.  
Да и вообще перешла на сайт Занимательных Задач. Старею, видимо, думать не хочется...

Comment: Ничего, у меня это уже лет сорок.   
  
>Да и вообще перешла на сайт Занимательных Задач   
  
Адресочком поделитесь? Я такого не знаю. 
Да, форумы без модерации вырождаются. 
Раньше это было по-другому, но соцсети убили "свободные" форумы...

Comment: [Логические задачи и головоломки](http://smekalka.pp.ru/)

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Забавный форум...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocentI, Это "олбанский", а олбанский не нормируется. Поэтому могут писать как угодно. 
Я чаще встречался с баяном, хотя сам пишу боян. думаю, что именно с Бояном и связан.

Answer (score 6):

Помимо сказителя Бояна, есть еще одна версия, которая мне нравится.

Раньше, когда много текстов приходилось писать от руки, при письме часто использовали знак -//-, чтобы обозначить повторение. Этот знак и есть  гармошка, "баян".

Answer (score 3):

Лурк рекомендует писать через "а" (боян и тем более бойан - это варианты из "йазыка падонкаф") и появление мема связывает с анекдотом "Хоронили тёщу. Порвали два баяна", который постили настолько часто, что данный анекдот стал синонимом старой заезженной шутки. Далее распространилось по интернету.

Из других возможных вариантов упоминается и знак повтора "-//-", остальные версии маловероятны.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше замените словом "аккордеон". 
Смысл не меняется, проблем не вызывает, да и звучит красноречивей. 
**:**)

Answer (score 0):

Баяном также именуют шприц с наркотой.

Comment: Мало ли что